# What do unrecognized GET requests mean?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, get-request

It's a new Amazon EC2 instance, it's live maybe a couple of hours a day, I've just installed NodeJS and still playing with it. And then I get this in my Putty SSH window:

[image]

I don't know what those two last requests mean. I don't have robots.txt and I definitely don't have any HTML file whatsoever (it's all in Jade).

Do I havet to be concerned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably a bot. Generally you don't need to worry about it, unless they are generating to many requests to the point that it causes performance issues with your application.

Comment: Thank you! That was my guess too. I closed all the ports suggested by Amazon and then I get this and was about to freak out.